# Getting data from the end

Tags: mysql, sql

I retrieve data from db like that:

```
select * from MOVIE_COMMENT where USER_ID = 102 LIMIT 10
```

This gives data to me with ids:

```
20
21
22
23
24
26
29
30
31
42
```

What I want is that receiving data from end related user like that:

```
42
31
30
29
26
24
..
..
..
```

How can I do that?

Comment: What are you using mssql, oracle, mysql....?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select * 
from MOVIE_COMMENT 
where USER_ID = 102 
order by column_name desc
LIMIT 10
```

use `order by`?

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT * FROM MOVIE_COMMENT 
WHERE USER_ID = 102 
ORDER BY COLUMN_NAME DESC 
LIMIT 10
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want the last ten rows rather than the first, try sorting data using ORDER BY and DESC.

Answer (score 1):

> select * from MOVIE_COMMENT where USER_ID = 102 order by column_name desc limit 10;

This will give you what you want